# Google Tag Manager Form Submission without URL changing

Tags: javascript, dom, google-tag-manager, ajaxform

**Scenario:**

Ajax Based Contact Us form on a page `www.example.com/contact-us`

Successful Form submission : Page stays same , Thank you text is displayed. ( on the html side of things , an attribute of style=display:none is removed from the div and it shows the thank you page.

```
<div id="123" style="display:none"> Thank you </div>
```

**Approach 1**: I tried Form submission trigger, however, it triggers every time a user clicks on Submit button. Also, it triggers code for invalid form submission attempt

**Approach 2:** I selected Form Validation in GTM. However, `gtm.FormSubmit` event is not fired. So the code is never triggered.

**Approach 3:** I have created a DOM element variable, which on initial page load gives me the value of **style** attribute of div `id="123"`.

My expectation was on form submit, I will get the updated value of Style attribute of div id 123. But, the value is never updated.

How do I enable the trigger to fire only when `style="display:none"` is absent after submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is for you to manually and explicitly push an event onto the GTM dataLayer when the form submission is successfully. You would usually do this in the Ajax callback as follows

```
dataLayer.push({'event' : 'form_submitted'});
```

Then, in GTM, you would create a trigger of type Custom Event and you would enter the event name (form_submitted). This will cause your tag to fire whenever this event is pushed onto the dataLayer.